# Does it make sense to make a conditional Markovianity assumption?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Please do excuse if the title is somewhat vague. As we know, a discrete-time Markov chain is a sequence of random variables $S_1,S_2,\cdots$ with the Markov property - i.e.
\begin{equation}
P[S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}\mid S_{t}=s_{t},\cdots,S_{1}=s_{1}]=P[S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}\mid S_{t}=s_{t}]
\end{equation}

Could the Markov property be extended by considering the same process conditional on, say, another variable $X$? - i.e.

\begin{equation}
P[S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}\mid S_{t}=s_{t},\cdots,S_{1}=s_{1},X]=P[S_{t+1}=s_{t+1}\mid S_{t}=s_{t},X]
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can form such a model. For example, $X$ can be the vector of probabilities in the transition matrix.